# Angular 2+ & ngBootstrap - Shared Modals

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, ng-bootstrap

Is it possible to have a ngBootstrap modal as a shared component and use an instance of it in other components.

I'd like to have one Modal that prompts the user to delete a record and I'd like to re-use it across multiple components with different record types.

ngBootstrap site shows a "Components As Content" example but in that example it looks like the ModalComponent dictates whether to open or close the ModalContents. I'd like the ability to open/close an instance of a modal from another (arbitrary) component.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a **CommonModule** as below,

   ```
   import { NgModule} from '@angular/core';
   import { CommonModalComponent } from './modal.component';
   import { ModalDirective,ModalModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
   @NgModule({
     imports:[ModalModule],
     declarations: [ CommonModalComponent ],
     exports:[CommonModalComponent]
   })
   export class CommonModule {}
   ```
2. As you can see, **CommonModalComponent** is a declaration in
   CommonModule, Create that component as below,

   ```
   import {Component,Input, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
   import { ModalDirective } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

   @Component({
     selector: 'common-modal', 
     template: `
      <div bsModal #childModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
       <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
           <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">{{title}}</h4>
           <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="hideChildModal()">
             <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
           </button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
           <ng-content select=".modal-body"> </ng-content>
         </div>

         <div class="modal-footer">
           <div class="pull-left">
             <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="hide()"> Cancel </button>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
     `,
   })
   export class CommonModalComponent {
      @ViewChild('childModal') public childModal:ModalDirective;
      @Input() title?:string;
     constructor() {
     }
     show(){
       this.childModal.show();
     }
     hide(){
       this.childModal.hide();
     }
   }
   ```
3. Using the CommonModule and its components in the AppModule as below,

   ```
   import {Component, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
   import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
   import {CommonModule} from './common.module';
   import {CommonModalComponent} './modal.component';
   @Component({
     selector: 'my-app',
     template: `
       <div>
         <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="childModal.show()">Open modal</button>
       <common-modal  #childModal [title]="'common modal'"> 
       </common-modal>
       </div>
     `,
   })
   export class App {
     @ViewChild('childComponent') childComponent:CommonModalComponent;
     name:string;
     constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
       this.name = 'Angular 2 Common Module with ModalComponent'
     }
   }

   @NgModule({
     imports: [ BrowserModule,CommonModule ],
     declarations: [ App ],
     bootstrap: [ App ]
   })
   export class AppModule {}
   ```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/TyvCfbntYGHhaLI5fbeq?p=preview)**

**Additional Information**:

1. This common module can be used any where to reproduce your needs
   with the help of ContentProjection in Angular 2 which can be seen in
   below line

   ```
   <ng-content select=".modal-body"> </ng-content>
   ```
2. In your AppComponent, you can use this and add items to your
   CommonModal as,

   ```
   <div class="modal-body"> 
           Some Form Controls or Displaying content
   </div>
   ```

   This can be seen in this [**LIVE DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/mykpjwdfP94ghMtTIols?p=preview)
3. Since, you want modal for warning messages or confirmation you can
   reuse the common-modal and create another **WarningModalComponent**
   and use that across application

Comment: I don't think that's the same ng-bootstrap he was asking about.

Comment: Read the post carefully, by this **re-use it across multiple components** yo u can reuse anywhere creating any number of modal components for any number of features.

Comment: He was asking about ng-boostrap from angular-ui and from what I see, you're actually using ng2-bootstrap from valor software.

Comment: @Aravind thats exactly what i was looking for but Adnan is right in that I use the ng-bootstrap library and what you wrote above doesn't apply even though it's exactly what I need

Answer (score 0):

Well, per their documentation when you instantiate the modal, you get the `NgbModalRef` instance. This instance has a property of the `componentInstance` that is, obviously, the instance of the component your using for your modal content.

For that to work, the component instance has to be injected with `ActiveModal` instance in its constructor which can give you access to its methods that you can later use.

```
open() {
  const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);

  // you should have access to the activeModal methods like dismiss
  modalRef.componentInstance.activeModal.dismiss("some reason");
}
```

You can use this to create a shared service that will keep the reference to the modal and manipulate it from any component.

Comment: I've seen that demo on their site but it doesn't quite make sense when sharing one template across two or more components...unless you got a working example