# Angular 2 import component from other module

Tags: angular

If app imports a component from another module, although the module only export this component, the complete module is brought to frontend. The only way to avoid it is put the component in a shared module and both module import the component?

Comment: Yes . . .  .. .  . . .

Comment: have a look at this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42633144/angular-2-ngbootstrap-shared-modals/42633720#42633720)