# How to use ngx-bootstrap modal as module?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, ngx-bootstrap

Is there an option to use [ngx-bootstrap modal](http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals) as module?

Comment: This [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42633144/angular-2-ngbootstrap-shared-modals/42633720#42633720) might help you

Comment: did you refer the above answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng2-bootstrap show/hide modal as child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42735858/ng2-bootstrap-show-hide-modal-as-child-component)